# Spring MVC 404 page not found

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have an `AuthenticationController` working fine: all of its methods are running and I can see the logged output of methods. After successful Authentication I return a new modal like this:

```
 modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/home/");
.....
 return modelAndView;
```

I have another controller named `HomePageController`, but, after returning a model from Authentication, I am not able to get the code execution in any method of `HomePageController`.

What mappings do I need?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
@SessionAttributes({"loginModel"})
public class HomePageController extends AbstractController {
```

Note: All methods in `AuthenticationController` are working fine..

web.xml file : http://snipt.org/vgEd7

mct-serverlet.xml file: http://snipt.org/vgEf2

Answer (score 1):

replace trailing space

```
 modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/home");
.....
 return modelAndView;
```

That will look for /home/index.htm or something.
 and in your HomepgageController, make sure there is some method, which returns view for /home url.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
@SessionAttributes({"loginModel"})
public class HomePageController extends AbstractController {    
    public string handleHomePage(){
        return "View Name";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this return statement : return new ModelAndView("redirect:home");
Avoid / in "redirect:/home/" after home action. It will look for index action automatically.